# What is stopping (not crashing) my windows service?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

We have a .NET Windows Service that occasionally shuts down on one particular server, about three times in the last month.  Logging shows that the `OnStop` method is being called, so I don't think the service is crashing.  However, we don't know what's shutting down the service.

Is there any way to find out what's shutting down the service? Is there anything I can log during `OnStop`? The Windows Event Viewer just shows application shut down and the security log does not show any user account authenticated at the time.

The service is running in .NET 3.5 SP1 on Windows Server 2003 SP2 (5.2.3790).

There are no service dependencies.  This service doesn't depend on any other services and no other services depend on this service.

Comment: Can you define crashing and stopping? My experience with window service is that when it hits an uncaught exception, it actually shuts down. But I did include the option to include error log in the event viewer log when such things occur.

Comment: @C_Rance, I could be mistaken here, but I believe when an unhandled exception occurs the app just stops, no more code executes.  Sometimes there's an event in Event Viewer with the error details, but not always.  In those cases, the logs just stop, no shut-down logs.  By contrast, when the app is shut down normally, the OnStop method is called and given an opportunity to close gracefully.  We have logging in OnStop and thus know that it is being called in the cases of our unexpected shut downs.

Comment: Does your service have any other service dependancies that might have shut down, causing your service to shut down?

Comment: @Samuel I believe u are correct to say when it hit exception, no more code executes. Hmm, kind of hard to debug given the way it works. Any threading used? A wild guess right now could be the server having improper shutdown. Like what u say, exception will not allow the logging to hit onStop. Proper shutting down might have some logging in event log

Comment: @Brain2000, good question, I just confirmed and there are no dependencies.  This service doesn't depend on any other services and no other services depend on this service. I'll update the question with this info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to tell from within the service since this called from the SCM - whoever asked SCM to stop your service isn't visible to the service...

I think your main option is checking the EventLog around that time... are other services being shutdown too ? is any scheduled taks running etc. ?

A "rather dirty" option (last resort/desperate) would be to set CanStop to false... in this case there will be someone seeing a problem in stopping your service and "hopefully" ask you why your service is not stoppable...

Answer (score 0):

From my limited experience, permissions and security can tend to cause all sorts of problems for windows services.

Under what account does the service run? (E.g. System account, network service etc).

Something I've had to do in the past is setting up the service to run under a network account with appropriate permissions. You can do this from the **Properties** window (right-click on the service in the 'Services' management console. In the **Log On** select **This account** and choose the account you want to use and enter the account password.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  The service runs under the System account and doesn't need any network resources or additional permissions.

Comment: Can you replicate the behaviour? If so, you can use Visual Studio to attach to the running process to see what might be going on. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a50syb3%28v=VS.100%29.aspx